# too much xmlns attributes by <image>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, save, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to save d3 chart as a svg file and have some problem with images. My chart contains also some icons which are also .svg files but after saving these icons cannot be found. I got an error: **"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"**

I checked the html file and saw that image has two xmlns attributes:

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/search.svg" x="-134" y="19" width="2.5em" height="2.5em"/>
```

but it should be like this

```
<image href="images/search.svg" x="-134" y="19" width="2.5em" height="2.5em"></image>
```

Can someone explain me how to resolve this problem? I'd appreciate any help

Here is the part of code where I'm putting image for my d3tree

```
 nodeEnter.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
              if (d.nodetype === "contact") {
                switch(d.categorie) {
                    case "0001": return "image/search.svg";
                    //....

                }
            }
        })
```

and here is function

```
    function saveAsSVG() {
var canvas = d3.select("svg").html();
var svg = '<?xml.... "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[' +this.styles + ']]></style>' + canvas + '</svg>';

var imgsrc = "data:application/svg+xml;base64," +btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)));
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.download = "export" + ".svg";
a.href = imgsrc;
a.target = "_self";
a.click();
```

}

sorry for the formatting problems. that's all what I have.

Comment: That's not a problem. Note they are different attributes, one is xmlns:xlink and the other is xlink:href. Your desired markup with href would, however not render as href is wrong.

Comment: The `xmlns:xlink` attribute is necessary.  Your second line is not correct.

Comment: ok. but why then my svg-icon doesn't show up? what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably the path to images/search.svg is wrong. The base directory isn't what you think it is I imagine.

Comment: but it works before saving. I mean only saved svg file can't display icons. here is some part of the code     `nodeEnter.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
                if(d.nodetype === "account") {
                    switch(d.role) {
                        case "001": return "images/search.svg";`

Comment: how should I change the path to images/search.svg ?

Comment: The information required to answer that is not in the question. What does "it works before saving mean?" Your code seems to be creating a new image (although you should add it to the question as code in comments is not readable).

Comment: I updated my main post. I'll hope it will be helpful

Comment: Is the SVG saved in the same folder as the original HTML?  If not, the relative image URLs won't be valid.

Comment: yes, you're right. it was saved in another folder. and how to save it in folder which I want because every browser saves it in different locations?